# how to make mpirun only be run from PBS

Tags: restriction, pbs

As an administrator of a HPC, I want to restrict users to run mpirun from terminal. But users should be able to use mpirun command from the pbs script. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Different admins take different approaches on this:

1. Use pam. Configuring [pam](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/3-nodes/hostSecurity.htm?Highlight=pam) makes it so that only certain users are allowed to ssh to a host.
2. Use something like the [reaver](http://www.nics.tennessee.edu/~troy/pbstools/) script from pbstools. This script can be configured to either kill processes that can't possibly belong to active jobs or simply notify you.
3. Other admins just manually catch users who do it (by noticing that the load is too high on a node, jobs are running slower, etc.) and then punish them severely so they don't do it again.

There are probably other methods different people use, but these are the ones that I come across most frequently.